# Check if time is greater that current time and take action on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have 2 columns in a row, one has a time stamp and another has current time, I put in another cell to check if time difference is greater than 2 hours and if yes it should say "Active else "Inactive" unfortunately the formula I input does not work.

In the formula, I input =IF(H6-G6>TIME(2,0,0), "Active", "Inactive")

Ideally in the first cell of the formula it should say Inactive but it says Active. Not sure why. Attached the screenshot[image]

Comment: There is a good chance your "Times" have date parts that are formatted to not show.

Comment: What are the value when you change them all to "general"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INT` to subtract out the day portion:

```
=IF(H6-INT(H6)-G6+INT(G6)>TIME(2,0,0), "Active", "Inactive")
```

[image]

or `MOD`:

```
=IF(MOD(H6,1)-MOD(G6,1)>TIME(2,0,0), "Active", "Inactive")
```